# Popup window in Inkscape extension

Tags: inkscape

I would like to build an Inkscape extension that only tells the user te total area of the selected item(s) - not modify them.

To do that I am looking for a way to create a popup feedback window in Inkscape that provides that info to the user. Right now I know that I create a window that looks like this:

[image]

but I would like to do something less ugly. Is that possible?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) (don't just change your question to "How").
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but you'd need to use tkinter for that, which you can rely on for Inkscape users to be available.